# Can I use GA to monitor action per user?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

I have a form for submit registering a service. I want to track how many times user visit site before submitting this form
and can view this information per user.

I havent much experience with Google Analytics, but It seems does not provide analytics information per user.

Can I do what I want with just Google Analytics?

Comment: Why not use cookies?

Comment: Why do you want to see this data per user rather than a aggregate information such as the average number of visits before submitting the form?